# What is the use of endless jump in bootsector programming

Tags: assembly, infinite-loop, x86-16, bootloader, boot

I was reading a book on how to build an OS and I came throught this code, all the code does is print hello but I want to know more about the endless jump:

```
  mov ah,0x0e
  mov al,'H'
  int 0x10
  mov al,'e'
  int 0x10
  mov al,'l'
  int 0x10
  mov al,'l'
  int 0x10
  mov al,'o'
  int 0x10

  jmp $

  times 510-($-$$) db 0
  dw 0xaa55
```

I know that `jmp $` jumps to itself.

I really want to *why* they have used an infinite loop in the middle of code. What is the use of it???

Comment: What else would you do once your program is done?

Comment: in the above program , nothing. I am just learning the basics of os devlopment

Comment: the program just prints hello and waits

Comment: can u also tell me why they have use jmp before times!!??? how is times is executed if the endless loop is the executed first???

Comment: @Rhymoid can u please help me out with this?? I need to know about it badly

Comment: `times` is not an instruction. It's an assembly-time prefix telling NASM to assemble what comes after it N number of times.

Comment: _"why they have used and endless jump in the middle of code"_ there's no code after that jump - only data. First a bunch of padding, and finally the boot record signature (0xaa55).

Comment: Times is not an CPU instruction it is an assembler directive that repeats something a specified number of time: in this case `db 0` . A bootsector for a floppy is 512 bytes long and must end with the word vaue `0xaa55`. The times directive using `510-($-$$)` effectively pads out the boot sector to 512 bytes with enough space for 0xaa55 at the end. When your bootloader is finished executing instructions you want you need to have the CPU busy doing something (infinite loop of some kind) so that CPU just doesn't continue walking through memory executing random garbage.

Comment: `jmp $` for an infinite loop does the job but often (preferable) method is putting the `hlt` instruction inside a loop. Something like `cli` `endloop: hlt` `jmp endloop` . If you've installed interrupt handlers (which you don't in your example) and need them to be processed then remove the `cli` before the loop.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks a lot for your asnwers!! I JUST WANT to know one more thing . I know times is not a instruction but still if the boot goes to a endless loop then how will you able to put the padding and the magic number?? is time being executed first??

Comment: @MichaelPetch please bare with me!! I am just confused!!! on why times is placed after the endless jmp

Comment: @MichaelPetch 510-($-$$) i know $ is current address but what will be value of this expression i mean what in terms of maths

Comment: `$$` is the address at the beginning of the current section. Since no section is specified it is assumed to be the address of the first data/code . You use ORG 0x7c00 so the value of `$$` will be 0x7c00. `$` is the current program counter at that point in the file. `$$-$` would then be the number of bytes the actual code you wrote so far takes up. 510 minus that value would be the number of bytes that need to be filled with `db 0` (or a 0 byte) to make the file exactly 510 bytes long. After that the boot signature is placed in the last two bytes. That totals 512 bytes the size of a boot sector

Comment: @MichaelPetch can u tell me if it matters if jmp is placed before times??? if no then will the times be executed no matter even if we are in endless jump?

Comment: `times` is not something that will be executed when you run the assembled code, but before. In this case, the `times` directive tells the assembler to write bytes with value 0 until there are 520 bytes in the output. This is because the signature `55 AA` must be at the 521st and 522nd byte of a bootloader, or the BIOS won't load it. `times` is something that's done at compile-time, not at run-time. And yes, it must come after the infinite loop in this case.

Comment: @Rhymoid : Think you mean 510 (not 520) and the last two bytes (Byte 511 and 512 in 1 based numbering) are the boot signature.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You are correct. I don't know what I was thinking :$

Comment: @KeyStroke : If you place the _JMP_ after the `times` directive then the CPU will attempt to decode all the zeros (`db 0`) as potential instructions before the _JMP_ which is not what you want. When you bootlooader is finished there aren't a whole lot of useful things to do besides toss it in an infinite loop or possibly rebooting the machine. For testing code rebooting is probably not ideal.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks a lot for your time! did help me a lot

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Why do this assembly program end with a infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135174)

Answer (score 2):

It does exactly what you think it does: it causes your program to freeze. It's usually done when your code just prints something to the screen and ends, and doesn't need to take any additional input beyond that. Since there's no operating system to return to, you need some way to "trap" the program counter, and this is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Worth mentioning (as Michael Petch did in comments), that putting a `hlt` inside the loop is preferable to save power; the CPU pauses until the next interrupt instead of running jumps as fast as it can (1/clock on modern CPUs).

Comment: Fair enough. I typically only leave the computer on long enough to write down what I care about when doing this anyway